# 'the end of next week' versus 'end of the year'

Tags: articles

The both example sentences come from https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/end

> Both Governments are working towards brokering a deal before **the end of next week**.
>
> Many say the two new injections could be made available to the public **by end of the year**

Why does the former have the definite article 'the' before 'end' while the latter doesn't?

Comment: To my ear, the second one sounds awkward - if I were leaving out the first article, I'd also leave out the second one as well: "...available to the public by **end of year**." I also feel that sounds a bit like "business speak."  I'd use it in a corporate email, for example.

Answer (score 2):

In your example sentences, the use of the article "***the***" is stylistic, there is no grammatical reason.

There is no difference in meaning between

> **the end of next week**
>   **end of next week**